# Does an actor guarantee the same execution thread?

Tags: swift, multithreading, actor

I'm working with sqlite so I need to guarantee the thread my calls execute on, but I don't want to use the main thread. I could subclass Thread, however that introduces a host of issues trying to create async methods and executing blocks of code in the thread's main loop.

If instead I used an actor instead of a Thread subclass, will all the work within that actor be guaranteed to be on the same thread? I don't see that defined anywhere in the documentation so I'm guessing no.

Comment: no it isn't if you search on SO you will find a couple of questions on the topic

Comment: No, not required to be same thread. BTW, if you use GCD serial queue, it's not guaranteed to be the same thread, either. But SQLite doesn't care. So why do you “need to guarantee the thread my calls execute on”?

Comment: Apple is rather blunt in their GCD documentation about getting developers away from threading, which is why they made GCD, an abstract that uses tasks to leave all threading to the framework and not the developer. I would leave all threading to Swift and work with GCD or async/await.

Comment: @Rob iOS uses the multithreaded build. "In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads provided that no single database connection is used simultaneously in two or more threads" I want to guarantee the thread used for all my database calls.

Answer (score 3):

You asked:

> Does an actor guarantee the same execution thread?

No, it does not. (Neither does GCD serial queue, for that matter.)

But SQLite does not care from which thread you call it. It only cares that you don't call it from different threads simultaneously.

So, you do *not* have to ”to guarantee the thread my calls execute on“, but merely ensure that you don't have two threads interacting with the same connection at the same time. This is precisely the assurance that actor-isolated functions provide.

So, do not worry about what thread the actor happens to use. Only make sure you don't have simultaneous access from multiple threads at the same time.